# Fourier transform of triangular pulse

Tags: fourier-transform

[Triangular pulse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs0o9.png)

[Calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEFhN.png)

I am having a hard time figuring out,  how the above-highlighted integral is derived.
Any hints would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlighted integral is a change of variable, although they didn't change the letter used to represent the two variables. Try doing the substitution $u = -t$ and then replace the $u$ with $t$ once you're done, and you get the given result.